# Running Shell and Python Scripts (that write to files) with Launchd

Tags: python, shell, automation, cron, launchd

I am surprised by the lack of information/videos on the internet about launchd. Anyways, I am fairly new to writing shell scripts and python in the Mac terminal, but am trying to automate a script to write the datetime every 20 seconds to a file.

Below is my plist file written under ~/Library/LaunchAgents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.py.plist</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/Users/sammahle/bin/python_file</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The 'python_file' referenced in the script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
print 'Hello World'
datetime1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(datetime1)
```

and when I do launchctl list I find " - 1   com.example.py.plist"
I ran the same thing for the shell script below and again received the status code "1", which according to [LaunchD Plist not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586824/launchd-plist-not-working) means “Exit code 1 means the script exited with an error condition. If it exited with a 0 it would mean there were no errors.”

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World!" >> file.txt
```

My end goal is to run complex python scripts daily without having the program needing to be running all the time. If anyone knows a better solution (I choose launchd over cron because it is "preferred") please let me know.

Comment: Try replacing `ProgramArguments` with `Program`

Comment: Tried that to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you make your script executable? Start **Terminal** and run `chmod +x /Users/sammahle/bin/python_file`

Comment: Yes, do I have to edit the permission of the file I am writing to?

Comment: Three things... 1) Try writing to a file with an absolute path so you are sure where you are writing, e.g. `/tmp/file.txt` 2) Open up the permissions on that file with `chmod 777 /tmp/file.txt` 3) Try running the script directly from the Terminal `/Users/sammahle/bin/python_file` and make sure it works like that.

Comment: It was the absolute file path on the text file. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cool - glad it is sorted out. Good luck with your project and come back if you get stuck again - questions (and answers) are free!